# NoSuchMethodError org.renjin.gnur.api.Utils.R_qsort_I

Tags: renjin

Trying to execute RandomForest on sample dataset, but facing method was not found issue as below.

Using the below libraries.

Using these external libraries.
bitops-1.0-6-b237.jar
caTools-1.17.1-b220.jar
renjin-script-engine-3.5-beta65-jar-with-dependencies.jar
gcc-runtime-0.8.1938.jar
rpart-4.1-10-b20.jar

Executing the RandomForest classification algorithm with this code.

```
RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
        engine.eval("dataset = read.csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')");
        engine.eval("dataset = dataset[3:5]");
        engine.eval("dataset$Purchased = factor(dataset$Purchased, levels = c(0, 1))");
        engine.eval("library(caTools)");
        engine.eval("set.seed(123)");
        engine.eval("split = sample.split(dataset$Purchased, SplitRatio = 0.75)");
        engine.eval("training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)");
        engine.eval("test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)");
        engine.eval("training_set[-3] = scale(training_set[-3])");
        engine.eval("test_set[-3] = scale(test_set[-3])");
        engine.eval("library(randomForest)");
        engine.eval("set.seed(123)");
        engine.eval("classifier = randomForest(x = training_set[-3], y = training_set$Purchased, ntree = 10)");
        engine.eval("y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-3])");
```

Getting the exception below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: org.renjin.gnur.api.Utils.R_qsort_I(Lorg/renjin/gcc/runtime/DoublePtr;Lorg/renjin/gcc/runtime/IntPtr;II)V
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.applyPromised(Closure.java:212)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.UseMethod.apply(UseMethod.java:166)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.applyPromised(Closure.java:200)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:133)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.assignLeft(AssignLeftFunction.java:58)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.apply(AssignLeftFunction.java:42)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.sexp.ExpressionVector.eval(ExpressionVector.java:85)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:280)
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:174)
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:133)
    at RTest.main(RTest.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.renjin.gnur.api.Utils.R_qsort_I(Lorg/renjin/gcc/runtime/DoublePtr;Lorg/renjin/gcc/runtime/IntPtr;II)V
    at org.renjin.cran.randomForest.rfutils__.makeA(rfutils.c:76)
    at org.renjin.cran.randomForest.rf__.classRF(rf.c:218)
    at org.renjin.cran.randomForest.randomForest.classRF(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.renjin.primitives.Native.dotC(Native.java:190)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$$C.applyPromised(R$primitive$$C.java:69)
    at org.renjin.sexp.BuiltinFunction.apply(BuiltinFunction.java:100)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Promise.doEval(Promise.java:87)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Promise.force(Promise.java:81)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$$bracket.applyPromised(R$primitive$$bracket.java:34)
    at org.renjin.sexp.BuiltinFunction.apply(BuiltinFunction.java:100)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.assignLeft(AssignLeftFunction.java:58)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.apply(AssignLeftFunction.java:42)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:39)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.IfFunction.apply(IfFunction.java:40)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:39)
    at org.renjin.sexp.FunctionCall.eval(FunctionCall.java:80)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.applyPromised(Closure.java:200)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Using these libraries. bitops-1.0-6-b237.jar caTools-1.17.1-b220.jar renjin-script-engine-3.5-beta65-jar-with-dependencies.jar gcc-runtime-0.8.1938.jar randomForest-4.6-12-b11.jar renjin-gnur-runtime-0.8.1938.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are some binary incompatiblities between the new 3.5 beta builds and packages built for Renjin 0.9. For the time being, using Renjin 0.9.2726 should avoid the problem.

Renjin 3.5 should be released before the end of September and will include new builds for all CRAN+BioConductor packages.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I tried with gcc-runtime-0.9.2726.jar, renjin-gnur-runtime-0.9.2715.jar but still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks @akbertram i tried with renjin-script-engine-0.9.2726.jar with all the required libraries and it is working fine. thank you so much.